# Convert text header of image appended to node in typical graph of nodes and link, to image in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I would like to add header to my nodes in d3. But instead of appending it as text I want to append it as image so that in graph scenario all lines will be below header and picture will look cleaner.

Currently because of many links picture looks messy which I want to avoid.

```
node.append('text')
.attr("class","label")
.attr("style","font-size:12px;")
.html(function(d){ 
        return d.name;  
    }
})
.attr("x",0)
.attr("y",-radius);
```

Is there any way how to do this. I read about hidden canvas but not sure exactly how to use here as I am beginner in D3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can [append an image](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) as well.

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/az2oks2b/) here, to showcase a working example of appending an image(icon) inside a circle.

```
node.append("circle")
         .attr("cursor","pointer")
          .attr("cx", 200)
         .attr("cy", 200)
         .attr("r", 25)
         .style("fill","white")
         .style("stroke", "black")     
         .style("stroke-width", 2);

node.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXWH.png")
    .attr("x", 185)
    .attr("y", 185)
    .attr("width", 32)
    .attr("height", 32);
```

You might also find this [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130) helpful.

Comment: Hi Taha,I think you misunderstood my question. Suppose text is Frank then I need to convert it as image as below and then append on another image.  http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.picgifs.com%2Fname-graphics%2Ffrank%2F&h=0&w=0&tbnid=-wvaPEgQHC50CM&zoom=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=238&docid=uZf63Gi27MnGNM&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&ei=s1lNVO7rFYT7igKCk4DwDA&ved=0CAQQsCUoAA&biw=1535&bih=803